# how did you extract ID3 tags metadata using exoplayer? can you please share your code.

Tags: android

can anyone tell me how can I extract meta from HLS stream ID3 tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-1-whats-new-2832c09fedab

```
@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
  for (int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++) {
    TrackGroup trackGroup = trackGroups.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < trackGroup.length; j++) {
      Metadata trackMetadata = trackGroup.getFormat(j).metadata;
      if (trackMetadata != null) {
        // We found metadata. Do something with it here!
      }
    }
  }
```

UPDATE: 
If you wish to receive and handle ID3 metadata then add an EventListener to the player via ExoPlayer.addListener.

```
    EXOPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            for (int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++) {
                TrackGroup trackGroup = trackGroups.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < trackGroup.length; j++) {
                    Metadata trackMetadata = trackGroup.getFormat(j).metadata;
                    if (trackMetadata != null) {
                        // We found metadata. Do something with it here!
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekProcessed() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could not override onTracksChanged method in my code. it shows 'method can't override it's super class methods'.

Comment: User: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236581/fergdev has given he has solved it by using exoplayer. But could not write a comment as I don't have reputation. If he could help, it will be a great help to me.